# Google apps script - Iterate through elements / widgets / controls

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

can someone tell me, how to iterate through UI elements / widgets, which has been created by myselft using app.create[Widget] command ?
Example:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var panelMain = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("PanelMain");
  app.add(panelMain);


  var rb1 = app.createRadioButton().setId("Rb1");
  panelMain.add(rb1);

  var rb2 = app.createRadioButton().setId("Rb2");
  panelMain.add(rb1);


  *************************************************************
   AND NOW I WANT TO ITERATE THROUGH ALL CREATED ELEMENTS
    (MAINPANEL,RB1, RB2)

   Something like:
   var allElemts = app.getElements();
   for (var ele in allElements){
   Logger.log(ele.name);
   Logger.log(ele.type);
   ........
   }

  *******************************************************
  **** DO SOMEONE KNOW - HOW TO DO *************************
  ***************************************************************



  return app;
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As there is no function to obtain elements on a widget like you want.

The best option is to use the Ids you use when creating elements, for instance:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var ids = [];

  var panelMain = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("PanelMain");
  app.add(panelMain);


  var rb1 = app.createRadioButton().setId("Rb1");
  panelMain.add(rb1);

  var rb2 = app.createRadioButton().setId("Rb2");
  panelMain.add(rb1);
  //store collection of ids from all widget
  ids.push(panelMain.getId());
  ids.push(rb1.getId());
  ids.push(rb2.getId());

  var allElemts = app.getElements();
  for (var id in ids){
    var element = ids[id];
    Logger.log(element.name);
    Logger.log(element.type);
  }
      return app;
```

}